# css transition only works within setInterval? why?

Tags: javascript, css-transitions

At a certain point in a script the following occurs

CSS-CODE

```
.tt{ opacity: 0; transition: all 1s;}
```

JS-CODE (THIS DOES NOT TRANSITION)

```
  this.element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',`<div class="tt">this is a message</div>`);
  this.tooltip = this.element.querySelector('.tt');
  this.tooltip.style.opacity = 1; => THIS DOES NOT TRANSITION
```

BUT WHEN I CHANGE MY CODE IN (THIS DOES TRANSITION)

```
  this.element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',`<div class="tt">${this.element.dataset.tooltip}</div>`);
  this.tooltip = this.element.querySelector('.tt');
  setTimeout(function(){
    this.tooltip.style.opacity = 1 => THIS DOES TRANSITION
  }.bind(this),0);
```

WHY? (even if the setTimeoutdelay is set to 0)

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING?

Comment: @JeremyThille was not shouting. Wanted to make it clear in a typographical way...

Comment: On the internet, uppercase = shouting (except in article titles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitions occur between one rendered state and another.

Your first code block changes the opacity property before the element has been rendered at opacity 0.

Adding timeout introduces a delay in which the element can be rendered at opacity 0.

> even if the setTimeoutdelay is set to 0)

`setTimeout` has a minimum delay on it, and even if it didn't, the queue of jobs would probably have repaint above the next timed action.

Comment: Is the setTimeout ‘trick’ then a correct workaround? Or would you suggest something else?

Comment: @Quentin yes that is why I deleted my comment.